# Compare date against date in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell

I have a function that is for a maintenance window. I am trying to figure out the way I have done it, is actually the best way.

I am passing in a date in the format "2015-05-07 01:00+13:00" and want to compare it against the date it is ran. i.e. today's date for this purpose.
The date passed in will get passed in with a variable, and for testing I just manually enter it. Hence the HelpMessage.

What I have so far I think works, I am sure there is a more efficient way of running what I want.

The code is below:

```
Function Get-MaintenanceWindow {
PARAM (
[cmdletbinding()]
    [Parameter(Position=1,
        Mandatory=$True,
        HelpMessage="Enter maintenance window to compare against i.e 2015-05-07 01:00+13:00")]
    $Window
)
    # Pass in two var and compare against, if $window1 < $Window2 still in Window
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host " * * * Running Function Maintenance Window * * * "
    #Compares two dates
    $TodaysDate = (Get-Date)
    $xTodaysDate = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddhhmm $TodaysDate)
    $xWindow = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddhhmm $Window)

    Write-Host "Today's date is : $xTodaysDate, compared to date is : $xWindow"

    Write-Host "Comparing against today's date $xTodaysDate against passed date $Window..."
    If ($xTodaysDate -lt $xWindow) {
        Write-host $xTodaysDate " is less than `$xWindow $xWindow, still in Maintenance Window!"
        $global:Check = $True
        }
    Else {
        Write-Host "Not in Maintenance Window, exiting..."
        #$Y = (Get-Date) +  " is less than `$Window $Window, still in Maintenance Window!"
        $global:Check = $False
        Break #Exits Function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a (way) easier way to do this. PowerShell (i.e .NET) is really cool with dates.

```
    $TodaysDate = [DateTime]::Now
    $xWindow = [DateTime] $Window
```

It'll automatically parse the date for you, and it works pretty well. See these examples:

```
$date = [DateTime] "5:00 PM"
$date = [DateTime] "Mon, Jan 5, 2014"
$date = [DateTime] "May 4"
```

Comment: I am getting this results - 7/05/2015 12:00:38 p.m. is less than $xWindow 01/05/2015 01:00:00, still in Maintenance Window! This is wrong, The result should be out of the maintenance window. I think it is due to my NZ format there server is working on and the American date being passed in.

Comment: @User79.Net If you need to parse a specific date format, it's better to use `[DateTime]::ParseExact()` for parsing a string into a date, e.g.: `[DateTime]::ParseExact($datestring, 'dd\/MM\/yyyy', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @User79.Net Unfortunately TimeZones aren't built into DateTime. You need to convert them to Universal (UTC) times first (`$date.ToUniversalTime()`), or deal with the offsets yourself.